# AdMob width of advert

Tags: android, admob

I've implemented ad mob into my app, but the banners are portrait size and my app is landscape. The orientation is fine, but the width doesn't fill the entire width of the screen. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the 320x50 banner ad is the only non-tablet size ad that AdMob offers (you can always create.  It doesn't fit a landscape layout as nicely as it does a portrait one, but you'll have to make it work for now.

EDIT:

As of AdMob SDK v6, there is a new format called "smart banner" which is also available for phones.  This format gets the dimensions of the screen to always request an ad that fills the entire width of the screen.  Smart banner ads will be full_width x 50 for phones in portrait, and full_width x 32 for phones in landscape.  See the [AdMob docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners) for more information.